# how to assign list element name to sheetName

Tags: r, xlsx

I'm trying to assign the name of each list element to the sheetName in write.xlsx, while creating new sheets for each element. I'm not sure how to work out the sheetNumber part in order to get the elements in the same sheet. Here is an example:

```
list_df = list('a'=data.frame(test1=NA,test2=NA),'b'=data.frame(test3=NA,test4=NA))
purrr::imap(list_df, ~write.xlsx(.x, "test.xlsx", sheetName = .y))
```

Note that this new edit was a partial solve by another member.

Comment: Hi @spazznolo. I had deleted my earlier attempt with `imap` because it didn't quite work. Please see below for a solution using `pwalk`. We need to use argument `append` to add sheets after initialising the file with the first sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `purrr::pwalk`

```r
purrr::pwalk(
    list(list_df, names(list_df), names(list_df) != names(list_df)[1]),
    function(x, y, z) write.xlsx(x, "test.xlsx", sheetName = y, append = z))
```

The third `z` argument is the entry of a logical vector, that is `FALSE` for the first element of your list and `TRUE` for all other elements, and that determines whether we append sheets to the Excel file (true for all list elements except the first).

Note that this is based on the `write.xlsx` function from the `xlsx` package. It seems that `openxlsx::write.xlsx` can directly write a named list to multiple sheets, see @RonakShah's answer.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and for introducing me to pwalk!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a named list of dataframes you can directly pass it to `write.xlsx` command.

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(list_df, 'test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Interesting. This does not work with `xlsx::write.xlsx`.

Comment: I had only ever used pmap before, so I'm happy to have learned imap and pwalk. I will also try tthe openxlsx package. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I hardly write things to excel but when I do I mostly use `openxlsx`.